# Check valid values of likert scales in R

Tags: r, spss

I'm a *SPSS* user trying to switch to R.

I have several variables in a data frame (`ea01` to `ea06`; `pre01` to `pre09`).

Data comes from a questionnaire and is in likert format (integer from 1 to 5).

SPSS has an option to validate the values of these variables, to check if all of them fall within the expected range, and show in which have invalid errors.

```
id ea01 ea02 ea03 ea04  
1  4    5    6    5  
2  3    2    1    3  
3  3    2    4    0  
4  5    3    4    3
```

Validation procedure should tell me that case 1 as an invalid value in variable `ea03` and case 3 in variable `ea04`.

How can this be done in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution would be (assuming your data called `df`)

```
lapply(df, function(x) which(!x %in% seq_len(5)))
```

Or if you want to create a custom function, could try

```
Validfunc <- function(x){
  l <- lapply(x, function(y) which(!y %in% seq_len(5)))
  Filter(Negate(function(...) length(...) == 0), l)
}
```

And then use it as in

```
Validfunc(df)

# $ea03
# [1] 1
# 
# $ea04
# [1] 3
```

---

Another option will be "*melting*" the data and subseting accordingly

```
library(data.table)
temp <- melt(setDT(df[-1]))
temp[, which(!value %in% seq_len(5)), variable]
#    variable V1
# 1:     ea03  1
# 2:     ea04  3
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also do:

```
indx <- which(df >5 | df < 1,arr.ind=TRUE)
setNames(indx[,1], names(df)[indx[,2]])
#ea03 ea04 
#1    3
```